# Generating a map like Arcmaps in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to generate a map of various locations. I want to generate it in R using leaflet package. I have latitude and longtitude of each locations. I have used following code but not able to generate. I am attaching a picture. I want this kind of graph.
[image]

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
jin_map=leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri") %>% 
  addMarkers(lng = jinesh_location_1_$Longitude, lat = jinesh_location_1_$Latitude)   
jin_map_circle<-jin_map%>%
  clearMarkers()%>%
  addCircleMarkers(data=jinesh_location_1_,radius = 2,color = "red",opacity = 0.70)
```

Comment: I think you want `addCircleMarkers()`

Comment: @SymbolixAU I have added. But not able to adjust size of circles. Like you see their are big circles.

Comment: use the `radius = ` argument to point to a column of your data - here's an example of using the `raidus` argument - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213357/106019

Comment: @SymbolixAU Can you help me making this sort of map. I will share data with you

Comment: if you edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(jinesh_location_1_) ) ` then anyone can help you.